# grepping /Library and "Too many levels of symbolic links"

Tags: macos, command-line, filesystem, symlink

I'm trying to clean up remnants of an application that was removed:

```sh
$ sudo grep -R "iNet Network" /Library
...
grep: /Library//Frameworks/Mono.framework/Home/lib/libmono-2.0.1.dylib.dSYM/libmonoboehm-2.0.1.dylib.dSYM: Too many levels of symbolic links
grep: /Library//Frameworks/Mono.framework/Home/lib/libmono-2.0.dylib.dSYM/libmonoboehm-2.0.dylib.dSYM: Too many levels of symbolic links
grep: /Library//Frameworks/Mono.framework/Libraries/libmono-2.0.1.dylib.dSYM/libmonoboehm-2.0.1.dylib.dSYM: Too many levels of symbolic links
grep: /Library//Frameworks/Mono.framework/Libraries/libmono-2.0.dylib.dSYM/libmonoboehm-2.0.dylib.dSYM: Too many levels of symbolic links
grep: /Library//Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.2.1/lib/libmono-2.0.1.dylib.dSYM/libmonoboehm-2.0.1.dylib.dSYM: Too many levels of symbolic links
grep: /Library//Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.2.1/lib/libmono-2.0.dylib.dSYM/libmonoboehm-2.0.dylib.dSYM: Too many levels of symbolic links
grep: /Library//Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/lib/libmono-2.0.1.dylib.dSYM/libmonoboehm-2.0.1.dylib.dSYM: Too many levels of symbolic links
grep: /Library//Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/lib/libmono-2.0.dylib.dSYM/libmonoboehm-2.0.dylib.dSYM: Too many levels of symbolic links
```

It's an unrelated issue to what I am trying to do, but I'd like to clean it up. I believe `libmonoboehm` is an Apple framework.

From [Too many levels of symbolic links](http://www.unix.com/unix-for-dummies-questions-and-answers/11324-too-many-levels-symbolic-links.html), its likely that soft links point to one another.

**Question**: How do I clear this error?

---

A quick `ls -l` on the first directory reveals the following. It almost appears the softlink refers to itself; or its parent directory, which appears to be named the same.

```
$ ls -l /Library//Frameworks/Mono.framework/Home/lib/libmono-2.0.1.dylib.dSYM/libmonoboehm-2.0.1.dylib.dSYM
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin  29 Aug 14  2013 /Library//Frameworks/Mono.framework/Home/lib/libmono-2.0.1.dylib.dSYM/libmonoboehm-2.0.1.dylib.dSYM -> libmonoboehm-2.0.1.dylib.dSYM
$ ls -l /Library//Frameworks/Mono.framework/Home/lib/libmono-2.0.dylib.dSYM/libmonoboehm-2.0.dylib.dSYM
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin  27 Aug 14  2013 /Library//Frameworks/Mono.framework/Home/lib/libmono-2.0.dylib.dSYM/libmonoboehm-2.0.dylib.dSYM -> libmonoboehm-2.0.dylib.dSYM
```

---

Related information.

- OS X 10.8.5 fully patched (and [still defective](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/180396/83961))
- Xcode Version 5.1.1 (5B1008)

Comment: [mono](http://www.mono-project.com) is an open source .net crossplatform dev framework. Already tried to un/reinstall it?

Comment: @klanomath - I did not install it, so I don't really feel comfortable removing it. I'm fairly certain it belongs to Apple. It may have been pre-installed or it may have been installed as part of Xcode. (And Disk Utility did not fix it).

Comment: Running `ls -l` on some of the listed files should give you an indication about there the symlinks are pointing to, maybe you have to follow the symlink chain for some steps. If you don't need `Mono.framework` any longer, it might be best to just delete it though.

Comment: *"I'm fairly certain it belongs to Apple"* - correction: according to @klanomath, its not an Apple framework. See his answer below. (And any reliable information on where it came from would be helpful since I might break something, and I'd like to know what that something is).

Comment: @jww I already mentioned [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/) in my answer. Which other cross-platform environments do you use?

Comment: @klanomath - that's kind of the thing.... I work in mobile security, and I have a C/C++/Objective C developer's background. I *think* would know if I installed an IDE and framework to develop for it. I don't believe in Mono or Wine, so I don't use them. (For purely philosophical reasons - on Linux, I write Linux programs; and on Windows, I write Windows programs. And if possible, I have one set of sources that compiles on both).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Mono.framework](http://www.mono-project.com/) neither belongs to Apple nor is it installed as a part of Xcode. I've cross-checked that with a VM (10.8.5/Xcode 5.1.1)

Checking your profile i'd suspect it was installed with Xamarin (or another cross-platform dev environment).

IMHO your Mono installation is hosed/got corrupted. A proper install looks like this (/Library/Frameworks):

[image: /Library/Frameworks]

Your path to Mono looks like this: /Library//Frameworks/Mono.framework/... (Please notice the double slash in the path).

So check your disk with Disk Utility first, then delete Mono.framework and the superior no name folder (or whatever it is), download the latest [Mono.framework installer](http://download.mono-project.com/archive/3.12.1/macos-10-x86/MonoFramework-MDK-3.12.1.macos10.xamarin.x86.pkg) and reinstall Mono.

Comment: *"Your path to Mono looks like this: /Library//..."* - yeah, that's an artifact from grepping with `/Library/` rather than `/Library`. You get the former with autocomplete (pressing tab).

Comment: BTW, thank you very much for going to the trouble of a VM install. That was above and beyond. This is one of those times I would like to reward someone for their extra effort. As you can see, the community wanted nothing to do with this: [Provide a means to reward users and their answers (decoupled from bounties)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239088/173448)

Comment: @jww No problem it took only 3 minutes. I have a VM for every major system (Client/Server) since 10.6 and using the snapshot feature it's a 5 second thing to revert to the vanilla system.