# iOS lifecycle (end-of-life dates)

Tags: ios

(Where) Does apple publish information about the release cycle for iOS?

Specifically I would like to know e.g. the end-of-life date (a.k.a. retirement date) for iOS 15.

I was looking for something like the [Ubuntu release cycle](https://ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle) page or the [Windows product lifecycle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/?products=windows) page, but could not find anything similar for apple OSes.

[This old answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/212068) suggests apple does not publish this information, is that still accurate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of this is guesswork, based on previous behaviour. Apple doesn't publish lifecycles & they don't really match those of other OSes at all. The best you can do is compare to prior historical behaviour- see [Wikipedia - iOS version history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_version_history) for a full history.

iOS doesn't have a lifecycle like a desktop OS.
macOS has a lifecycle of "the current & previous two" main releases, which means that once Ventura is released, Monterey & Big Sur will only get security updates, nothing else. Catalina & all that went before are dropped completely. It's very rare, though not totally unheard of, that anything older than this would ever see another update of any sort.

iOS, on the other hand has a single year per cycle. As soon as 16 comes out, 15 becomes unsupported.
However, because 15 is an end-of-life for some devices, it will see security updates for some time to come. Possibly one year.
Part of the reasoning behind this is that if you ever have to do a restore on a device, you will automatically get the current iOS, or the last that device is capable of running. Apple has zero interest in keeping out of date devices on out of date OSes.

As far as I'm aware, you can still restore all but the oldest iPhones to their original structure, assuming the Mac can still recognise them. I think Apple are slowly dropping support for devices over a decade old. Though my 2005 iPod will still sync, I haven't tried to do a full restore on it in several years. I have a 5S that would still restore, last time I tried a couple of years ago, but nothing older to test.

Comment: hmm… I might have an old 4 kicking around… might give it a try if I can find it & report back...

Comment: meh, I found a 3G & a 3GS… so far can't scare any life into either of them...

Answer (score 1):

I believe the closest answer is 5-7 years, based on [this document posted by Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201624).  From the doc,

> Products are considered vintage when Apple stopped distributing them
> for sale more than 5 and less than 7 years ago.

Given each version of iOS is released along with a new hardware model, one can assume that the version of iOS will be supported for the same 5-7 years as the hardware is.

Comment: That generally applies to the device's lifecycle & it's upgradability over that span, not that of any *single*  iOS.

Comment: That's a fair point @Tetsujin!